# Apache AH00124 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to track down what is causing these redirects. The most obvious answer is that I have something in my .htaccess file(s) that is causing this; but I don't know what specifically is causing it.  The problem though is that its a very ambiguous error, not telling me where, or which, htaccess file its coming from.

```
[Mon Mar 13 13:13:19.829021 2023] [core:error] [pid 20522] [client 23.105.39.107:44098] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I have three websites on my server, one primary WWW and two sub-domains - each main folder has its own .htaccess file.  I have to admit, htaccess syntax is very confusing for me and I am often messing things up.  So when I get it work I just leave a lone, but apparently even getting it to work is still causing issues.

```
root www (www.mydomain.com)
  |-- club (portal.mydomain.com)
  |-- api (api.mydomain.com)
```

www .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# api/portal conditions send traffic to the subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^api/ api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^club/ portal%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

# www and other hosts forced to HTTPS://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

portal .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

// are these redundant as they are already in the parent root folder?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^portal\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

#AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mydomain.com"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

api .htaccess file

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Pragma, Expires, Cache-Control, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400

// are these redundant as they are already in the parent root folder?   
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

## UPDATE:

ok, I found the culprit, but now I need assistance with how to manage it.

I added `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` to my httpd.conf file and found the offending IP (and others) are hitting the root directory of one my sub-domains and there is no default `index.html` file the root path of the sub-domain.  So then it tries to serve up a `400.shmtl` file from the same path - which also does not exist which in turn does a `forcing responsecode 403` to serve up `403.shtml` (which also does not exist), then it spits that out 10 times and stops when it hits the `LimitInternalRecursion` limit of 10.

My domain path:

```
   wwwroot - index.html (mydomain.com : all good)
       |- club/index.html (portal.mydomain.com : all good)
       |- api/ (api.mydomain.com : <=== culprit
                no index.html/400.shtml/403.shtml files)
          |- v1/ (no index.html file)
              | - images (needs open access)
              | - 0.40/ (no index.html file, but other *.php files)
```

So whats the best way to deal with this?

**The Goal**: I don't want anyone hitting the directory `/api/` or the `/api/v1/` directory - but do want users able to hit the `/api/v1/images/` and the `/api/v1/0.40/` directories.

1. Should I just add a `400.shtml` page to `/api/`?
2. Or should I add an `index.html` that only serves up`http_response_code(404);`
3. or can I put block rules in htaccess that would achieve the goal above?

The more I think about it, I think I just need to do something to manage `/api/` as it is a listed domain that bots/monitoring servers are trying to hit - so by default they are simply going to hit `https://api.mydomain.com` which the server is then going to try to serve up the default `index.html` file - which doesn't exist.

Comment: What URL do you enter in browser that causes this error?

Comment: @anubhava - I don't know what the url is.  I am seeing these messages in the `error_log` file - and as mentioned in the OP, its very ambiguous to where its coming from or what is causing it.  Where else can I look to see whats generating it?  Very few of the log messages have the URL in them.

Comment: First thing I would do is `grep` or `ack` the apache access logs for IP `23.105.39.107` -- This will at least get you to what domain they are requesting.  Then compare log times with the returns from your grep to your error log ...  That should help narrow things down a bit

Comment: @zak - found the culprit, see updated OP for details.  Thoughts?

Comment: What I do?  Put a `index.php` inside the higher directories like `/api/` and either serve an Ooops page or put a `header` in the top to redirect them so somewhere more appropriate.  Or better yet, serve a JSON response of 400 (Bad Request -- method not allowed) --  Sometimes it's easier to "deal" with traffic than it is to block it.

Comment: @zak - yup, pretty much what we did.  And we went through all sub-domains/paths cleaned everything up.  Our apache `error_log` had several hundreds of thousands of `AH00124` errors in them - which means there were several million redirects going on (10 per logged error).  Hopefully that just freed up a boat load overhead processing.

Comment: Not just processing, but the storage space on the error logs!